# RuntimeException: com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthException: oauth_token does not exist

Tags: java, gwt, oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to get the admin state of a user on a Google Apps domain.

I therefore have put the CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET I got from the Google Marketplace's listing of my App into my Code.

```
String CONSUMER_KEY = "748096634522.apps.googleusercontent.com";
String CONSUMER_SECRET = "PK/Wx/9sbLkz5hhj6rq6LKCZ";
```

And I've authorized the application to have access to the scope

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/
```

But when I try to access the URL

```
 https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/2.0/domain.com/username%40domain.com
```

I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.icada.idea.client.LoginInfo com.icada.idea.client.LoginService.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthException: oauth_token does not exist.
```

Trying on [Googles OAuth playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground) however works perfectly, whith the data provided above.

Here is my code:

```
private boolean isAdmin (String userEmail, String domain) {
  boolean ret= false;

  String CONSUMER_KEY = "748096634522.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  String CONSUMER_SECRET = "PK/Wx/9sbLkz5hhj6rq6LKCZ";

  GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
  oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
  oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
  oauthParameters.setScope ("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/");

  com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.UserService client
    = new com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.UserService ("Idea");
  try {
    client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
    URL feedUrl = new URL("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/2.0/"
      + domain +"/"+ java.net.URLEncoder.encode (userEmail));

    UserFeed resultFeed = client.getFeed(feedUrl, UserFeed.class);
    for (UserEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
      if (entry.getLogin ().getAdmin ().equals (Boolean.TRUE)) ret= true;
      else ret= false;
    }
  }
  catch (OAuthException ex) {
    log.severe (ex.getMessage () + ex.toString () + ex.getCause ()
      + ex.getStackTrace ().toString ());
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  [more catch-blocks...]

  return ret;
}
```

Any idea, why it says "oauth_token does not exist"?

Comment: Could you please post the https oauth request that gets sent over the wire

Comment: I don't know how I could do that. For the program runs on Google App Engine (where I obviously don't have access to) and the other side is the server my Google Apps account is running. So its 2 servers, I don't controll.

Comment: I am having the same trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your code.

oauthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH);

This may solve your problem.

Comment: This solved no auth_token, but here what i got next: java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information